# What should be the best and efficient way to find if a binary tree level has been completed or not?

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I am generating a binary tree of associates in a business model, where each member can have maximum of 2 sub members. Now I need to know whether a certain level in the tree has been completed or not. 
[image]

```
function binarytree($id = 1, $link , $supermember = false, $float = "left", $level =1)
    {
        $level++;
        if($level>3)
        {
            return false;
        }
        $width = 100;
        $res_count = 1;
        if($supermember)
        {    
            $res_count = 2;     
        }
        $query = "Select * from binary_tbl where id = $id";
        $res = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        $div_witdh =  $width/$res_count;
        while($r = mysql_fetch_object($res))
        {
                echo "<div style='width:$div_witdh%;text-align:center;float:$float'>$r->name<br>";
                $query_member = "Select * from binary_tbl where supermember = $id";
                $res_member = mysql_query($query_member, $link) or die(mysql_error());
                while($rm = mysql_fetch_object($res_member))
                {
                            $this->binarytree($rm->id, $link, true, $float, $level);
                            $float = ($float=='left')?'right': 'left';
                }       
                echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

I am using the following database relations to generate a binary tree using php code..

```
CREATE TABLE `binary_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supermember` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `membercount` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

I need to know if each level has been completed or not by running a single piece of code (it can be a cron php script), means whether all the parents of any given level have both of their hands full or not. What should be the most efficient way to look at this problem?

**Desired output:** *Bool value to denote whether each level is complete or not.*

Comment: recurse through the tree, find the terminal nodes, and see how many children are there. 0 children = complete, 2 children = complete, 1 child = incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping track of number of nodes on every level in a separate structure, might as well be a simple array. You already know the level of a node when inserting it, therefore updating the particular count at the time of insert is inexpensive

```
$countAtLevel[$level]++
```

After this, determining if a level is complete is simple, n-th level always contains `2^n` values.